# Is there a way to protect my R code that runs on a AWS account owned by a client?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, etl

I just joined a company that needs to build an ETL pipeline inside an AWS account owned by a client. 
There's one part of the ETL pipeline that runs a code written in R. The problem is, this R code is a very important part of our business, and our intelectual property. Our clients can't see this code. 
Is there any way to run this in their AWS environment without them having access to our code? R is not compilable, so we can't just deploy an executable file there. And we HAVE to run this in their environment. I suggested creating an API to run this in our AWS environment, but this is not an option.

Comment: Is this code running on an EC2 instance in their account? If not, what does the ETL workflow look like? Is there any way to run that step in *your* account, accessing *their* data using cross-account roles?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is. If a had the option, i would just deploy the code as an API in our environment, but this is not an option, the client require that the script is executed in their premises.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, these are the options I've realized in situations like this, in increasing order of difficulty:

1. Take the computation off-premises. This sounds like not an option for you.
2. Generate an API (e.g., `shiny`, `opencpu`, `plumber`) that is callable from their premises. This might require some finessing on their end, as I'm inferring (since they want it all done within their environment) that they might prefer a locked-down computation (perhaps disabling network access).
3. Rewrite the sensitive portions in `Rcpp`. While this does have the possible benefit of speed improvements, it makes it slightly harder for them to "discover" the underlying intellectual property. Realize that R and `Rcpp` are both **GPL**, which means that anything *linked* to by R must also be GPL, meaning source-code available. (It is feasible that since you are not making it *public* that you can argue your case here, but I am not a lawyer and would not want to be the first consultant found on the wrong side of GPL law here. Again, IANAL.)
4. Rewrite the sensitive portions in a non-R executable (note that I don't say *"as a non-R library and link to it via R calls"*, since the linking action taints the library with R's GPL). This executable can be called by your otherwise releasable R package (via `system` or `processx::run`).

   (For the record, one might infer C or C++ here, but other higher-level languages do allow compilable executables and are not GPL. Python has some such modes. Be sure to obfuscate your variables :-)

I think your "safest" options are #2 and #4.